# How to mock HTTP Error response with Charles?

Tags: charles-proxy

Is it possible to intercept the request going through Charles and immediately return 500 error code **without** sending this request to the server?

Can't find any information on this. All resources suggest to wait for the response and then change HTTP response code to 500.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already tried adding a rewrite rule to make the request to be returned with the 500 status. Have you tried combining this with a map local, to an empty file on your disk, for instance? It may work.

If this doesn't work too, I think I would do a Map Remote to another path on my localhost (for instance: http://localhost:8081/exected-response-500) and make that URL to return the 500 status error (in my case I would use a basic Spring Boot app to achieve this).

Comment: Eventually, today I came up with "Map local" with empty file + manual update of a response code to 500. But I still don't like the "manual update of a response code to 500" part. Will try the "Map remote" + Spring Boot.